# the size of thumbnail image is not changing and showing extra30x30 with it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress, thumbnails

i'm working on wordpress with twitter bootstrap theme. i just made a grid of images in my template with the plugin **display post shortcode**.

Here is the code for that :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts category="Uncategorized" image_size="thumbnail" posts_per_page="100000"]'); ?>
```

its workign nicely. i have taken the image_size as thumbnail and the size for this in my Settings > Media is 30x30.  now i have made this grid.but now my problem is that i want to change the size from 30x30 to 100x100 so i have change it from Settings > Media, but its not changing and after seeing my page through firebug its showing like this :

```
<img class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="30" height="30" alt="Yashika Bajaj" src="http://pearlacademy.com/history/wp-content/uploads/2998/09/Yashika-Bajaj-30x30.jpg">
```

i dont know why its adding extra -30x30into evry image.here i want to mention that my all images are of different sizes in original.

Comment: anybody is there please guys i need ur help.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in back office is to manage size for insert image in post not for featured image.
if you want to change the featured size, you have to add this in your function.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 100, 100, false ); // width, height, crop
}
```

Comment: @ Bertrand : yes i have done that its working ok but i want it done by thumbnail only so is there any way??

Comment: @ Bertrand : i have also tried that but nothing happening bro